# Issue with JAXB: nameXmlTransform typeName prefix not working

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

I wish to convert several schemas into Java Code.  The schemas are all similar; for example, each one has a TXLife root object.  It would be easier to manage the code if each schema generated code with unique class-names.  I can use the "package" binding to put the code from each schema into its own package, but when I try to use the "prefix" binding to change the class names, it ignores it.

Here is my schema_bindings.xml file:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" jaxb:version="2.0">
>    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schemas/HI_Request.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
>       <jaxb:schemaBindings>
>          <jaxb:package name="com.mycompany.hi"/>
>          <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
>             <jaxb:typeName prefix="Hi_"/>
>          </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
>       </jaxb:schemaBindings>
>    </jaxb:bindings>
> </jaxb:bindings>
> ```

When I run the xjc command I get (I had to modify the classpath inside the xjc.bat file in order to get it to work):

> C:\test>\progs\Java\jaxb-ri-2.2.7\bin\xjc.bat -extension -d src -b schema_bindings.xml schemas
>
> ```
> parsing a schema...
> compiling a schema...
> com\mycompany\hi\Holding.java
> com\mycompany\hi\InquiryLevel.java
> com\mycompany\hi\KeyedValue.java
> com\mycompany\hi\OLifE.java
> com\mycompany\hi\ObjectFactory.java
> com\mycompany\hi\Policy.java
> com\mycompany\hi\TXLife.java
> com\mycompany\hi\TXLifeRequest.java
> com\mycompany\hi\TransMode.java
> com\mycompany\hi\TransSubType.java
> com\mycompany\hi\TransType.java
> ```

What I was hoping for is that each java file (and the class inside) would be named "Hi_<name>".  Jaxb seems to be completely ignoring my "prefix" specification.
I have tried several variations on the bindings file.  I have also tried the same bindings using the Ant xjc task, all with the same results.

I can work with these results, but it would mean that code that processes input from one schema and produces output to another schema would have to use fully-qualified class names to refer to the objects, which is awkward.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### TL;DR

`<jaxb:typeName prefix="Hi_"/>` corresponds to the classes generated from named complex types.  You could do the following by adding `<jaxb:elementName prefix="Hi_"/>` to affect the classes generated from global elements:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" jaxb:version="2.0">
   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
      <jaxb:schemaBindings>
         <jaxb:package name="com.mycompany.hi"/>
         <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:typeName prefix="Hi_"/>
            <jaxb:elementName prefix="Hi_"/>
         </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
      </jaxb:schemaBindings>
   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

---

### Full Example

Below is a complete example.

**schema.xsd**

The schema below has a global element and a named complex type.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="GlobalElement">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="foo" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

    <complexType name="NamedComplexType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="bar" type="string" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

**binding.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" jaxb:version="2.0">
   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
      <jaxb:schemaBindings>
         <jaxb:package name="com.mycompany.hi"/>
         <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:typeName prefix="Type_"/>
            <jaxb:elementName prefix="Element_"/>
         </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
      </jaxb:schemaBindings>
   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

```
xjc -b binding.xml schema.xsd
```

**Output**

We see that the class corresponding to the global element was prefixed with `Element_` and the class corresponding to the named complex type was prefixed with `Type`.  `ObjectFactory` and `package-info` are not part of the domain model and are leveraged by JAXB for metadata so their names were not affected.

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
com/mycompany/hi/Element_GlobalElement.java
com/mycompany/hi/ObjectFactory.java
com/mycompany/hi/Type_NamedComplexType.java
com/mycompany/hi/package-info.java
```

Comment: It seems you have a lot of knowledges in binding. Could you please help me with my issue? I have stucked with it for 2 days. 1.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464605/schema-element-references-undefined-type-create-soap-client-service-how-to-tak
2.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802068/suffix-in-xjb-binding-doesnt-work-properly-java-wsdl