# Schema element references undefined type. Create SOAP client service. How to take into account binding customization of the generated classes?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cxf, xjb

I have converted WSDL to Java classes, however, I needed to use binding file and suffix added to resolve conflicts. I received classes successfully however with slightly changed type names.
When I try to create WebService using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean then I put URL of origin WSDL that has origin names and it gives errors like this:

> ERROR 6792 --- [nio-5500-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.w.s.f.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean : Schema element
>   {http://tempuri.org/}SearchMagistratesCourtRequest references
>   undefined type SearchMagistratesCourtRequest for service
>   {http://tempuri.org/}WebServiceService.

And that it right because my generated class has the name "SearchMagistratesCourtRequestType"- with "Type" at the end.

So my binding file used the following customization:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/egrul.xsd">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="ru.spi2.javaee.custom.pravoru.classes.egrul"/>
        <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:typeName suffix="Type"/>
            <jaxb:elementName suffix="Element"/>  //this one is not needed actually
        </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Here was used the suffix.

I create my WebService like this:

```
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean portFactory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    portFactory.setAddress(WSDL_URL);
    portFactory.setServiceClass(WebService.class);

    webService = (WebService) portFactory.create();
```

Here I put origin WSDL_URL and receive the described errors.

How can I take into account here the binding customization that was used to generate Java classes? Or what might be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by another initialization of the service. The binding works properly. 
So the correct working initialization of SOAP service in my case is the following:

```
private void initiateService() throws Exception{

    WebService_Service webService_service = new WebService_Service();

    webService_service.setHandlerResolver(new HandlerResolver() {
        @Override
        public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
            List<Handler> handlerList = new ArrayList<>();
            SOAPLoggingHandler soapLoggingHandler = new SOAPLoggingHandler();
            handlerList.add(soapLoggingHandler);
            return handlerList;
        }
    });

    webServicePort = webService_service.getPort(WebService.class);

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(webServicePort);

    Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

    Map<String, Object> props = ((BindingProvider) webServicePort).getRequestContext();
    props.put("ws-security.username", PravoRuConstants.USERNAME);
    props.put("ws-security.password", PravoRuConstants.PASSWORD);

    props.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    props.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, PravoRuConstants.USERNAME);
    props.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);

    props.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, PravoRuPasswordHandler.class.getName());

    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(props);
    cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

}
```

SOAPLoggingHandler:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

public class SOAPLoggingHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        SOAPMessage message= context.getMessage();
        boolean isOutboundMessage = (Boolean)context.get (MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if(isOutboundMessage){
            System.out.println("OUTBOUND MESSAGE\n");

        }else{
            System.out.println("INBOUND MESSAGE\n");
        }
        try {
            message.writeTo(System.out);
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        SOAPMessage message= context.getMessage();
        try {
            message.writeTo(System.out);
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) { }
}
```

PravoRuPasswordHandler:

```
import com.kirillch.constants.PravoRuConstants;
import org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSPasswordCallback;

import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PravoRuPasswordHandler implements CallbackHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {

        WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
        pc.setPassword(PravoRuConstants.PASSWORD);


        //      for(int i=0; i<callbacks.length; i++) {
        //          WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[i];
        //          if(pc.getIdentifier().equals(PravoRuConstants.USERNAME)){
        //              pc.setPassword(PravoRuConstants.PASSWORD);
        //              return;
        //          }
        //      }

    }
}
```